# Cannot read property 'dropdown' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to transform my code into a more plugin type of code, so everything will be separated, in case I change class names in the future.

For some reason, in my code, I get `Cannot read property 'dropdown' of undefined`.

My guess is, the function `Navigation.bindEvents()` runs before I set the config, so It can't find it... But I don't know how to solve it.

Here's my **Navigation.js** file:

```
let Navigation = {
    config: {},

    init(config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents() {
        $(this.config.trigger).on('click', this.toggleNavigation);
        $(document).on('click', this.hideAllDropdowns);
    },

    toggleNavigation(event) {
        // Store the current visible state
        var visible = $(this).siblings(this.config.trigger).hasClass('visible');


        // Hide all the drop downs
        this.hideAllDropdowns();

        // If the stored state is visible, hide it... Vice-versa.
        $(this).siblings(this.config.content).toggleClass('visible', !visible);

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    },

    hideAllDropdowns() {
        $(this.config.dropdown + ' ' + this.config.content).removeClass('visible');    
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

And here's my **app.js** file which I run all the `init` functions.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

import Navigation from './layout/navigation.js';


Navigation.init({
    dropdown: '.dropdown',
    trigger: '.dropdown-trigger',
    content: '.dropdown-content'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you got problem with the scope `$(document).on('click', this.hideAllDropdowns);`

Let's try

```
    bindEvents() {
        $(this.config.trigger).on('click', this.toggleNavigation);
        $(document).on('click', this.hideAllDropdowns.bind(this));
    },
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    bindEvents() {
        $(this.config.trigger).bind('click', {self:this}, this.toggleNavigation);
        $(document).on('click', this.hideAllDropdowns.bind(this));
    },
```

And replace all `this.config` by `event.data.self` inside `toggleNavigation` function

Comment: I added it for both of them, When I click the dropdown, It does nothing, compared to the previous situation, where I clicked and It said `Cannot read propery dropdown of undefined`.

Comment: The error still there? If not I think there is another problem in your click hanlder. Maybe you should using $(this.config.content) instead of $(this.config.dropdown + ' ' + this.config.content)

Comment: I fixed it, It was a problem related to the use of `this`, When inside a click handler `this` no longer referes to the object, in this case `Navigation` so I changed all the `this` statements to `Navigation`, Not sure if it's a good thing, but it worked. I will upvote this answer, because it gave me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Cool ! so I updated the answer to suitable with your problem

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the context of `toggleNavigation` refers to the clicked element.

That is why you can do `$(this).siblings(...)` to get the sibling elements.

You need to have a reference to the Navigation object. Perhaps you can use the `on` syntax that allows you to pass extra data `$(this.config.trigger).on('click', this, this.toggleNavigation);`

Then rewrite the handler

```
toggleNavigation(event) {
    //get the navigation reference
    var nav = event.data;
    // Store the current visible state
    var visible = $(this).siblings(nav.config.trigger).hasClass('visible');


    // Hide all the drop downs
    nav.hideAllDropdowns();

    // If the stored state is visible, hide it... Vice-versa.
    $(this).siblings(nav.config.content).toggleClass('visible', !visible);

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `this` is one of the hardest things to understand in JavaScript. Here `this` is obviously **dynamic**, which means that its value depends on where your method has been called...

```js
let module = {
  config() {
    console.log(`config(): 'this' is 'module' ---> ${Object.is(this, module)}`);
    console.log(`config(): 'this' is 'document' ---> ${Object.is(this, document)}`);
  },
  init() {
    console.log(`init(): 'this' is 'module' ---> ${Object.is(this, module)}`);
    console.log(`init(): 'this' is 'document' ---> ${Object.is(this, document)}`);
    
    module.config();
  }
};

$(document).ready(module.init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```